# Using DBMS error log, how can I bulk insert values from one table into another skipping (but logging) errors?

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to bulk insert rows from one table to another. I want to skip any errors that occur while doing this but log them as well. I used the following  PL/SQL command to create an error log table for the table I am trying to insert all the values into:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_ERRLOG.create_error_log (
      dml_table_name   => 'ROBOT_ID_TOOL_DUMP_IDPK.TEST'
      , skip_unsupported => TRUE);
END;
```

I then do a simple insert with logging turned on:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
LOG ERRORS INTO ERR$_table2;
```

The logging works but my insert is stopping, and rolling back after the first exception is hit (PK or unique constraint for example). I don't want to rollback when an exception is encountered though, I want that row to be skipped, and to continue trying to insert all remaining rows (but logging the problem row). I thought that is what the `skip_unsupported` parameter was doing. I have tried setting this value to FALSE and am still encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed a step on my insert.

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
LOG ERRORS INTO ERR$_table2 REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

The `REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED` flag Continues through every error.